# Python recursive function to create generic tree

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, tree

I'm trying to create a tree with n children for each node.
Problem is, when I try to implement this using a recursive function, I ends up with multiple recursive calls so I can't have a single `return` statement, hence having `None` as a final result.

Here is my piece of code :

```py
def recursive_func(tree, n):
    if n == 0:
        return tree
    else:
        permutations = get_permutations()
        for permutation in permutations:
            child_tree = recursive_func(Tree(permutation), n-1)
            tree.addChild(child_tree)
```

`get_permutations()` gives a list of child trees to create. I also have a `Tree` class with a node value and a list of children.

Here is the Tree class:

```py
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, result):
        self.node = node
        self.children = []

    def addChild(self, tree):
        self.children.append(tree)
```

This is probably a rookie error in the design of my problem, but I would be glad to get some help.

Comment: what is the return type of `tree.add`??

Comment: you say `I ends up with multiple recursive calls`

Can you please show us the output?

Also no need to say this is probably a rookie error, no one will get mad, well most people won't,  if you post something that is formatted properly!

Comment: `tree.addChild()` returns nothing, it just appends the child to the tree. I updated my post with the Tree class. As for the mention of multiple recursive calls, it is just because I have a for loop within the recursive call.

Comment: Why don't you just use *multiple* ``return`` statements or have one final ``return`` at the end (and remove the first branch)? It seems that the function should always ``return tree`` for all current branches.

Comment: Well, looks like it works @MisterMiyagi ! But I still don't really get why because I don't need `recursive_func()` to return something at the end so I thought the return statement within the `n == 0` condition was sufficient for the recursive function to run through the entire tree. Yet, it seems that I need to `return tree` anyway, right ?

Comment: Since you are using the result (in ``child_tree = recursive_func(…)``), yes, you should consistently return something.

Comment: OK, I think I get it. Should I answer my own question with a mention to your comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Since you use the result of `recursive_func`, it should always `return` its `tree`.

---

The `recursive_func` has three important points for this problem:

```
def recursive_func(tree, n):
    if n == 0:
        return tree  # 1.
    else:
        permutations = get_permutations()
        for permutation in permutations:
            child_tree = recursive_func(Tree(permutation), n-1)  # 2.
            tree.addChild(child_tree)
    # 3.
```

Now, `1.` defines that the function *sometimes* returns a `Tree`. This matches `2.` which *always* expects the function to return a `Tree`. However, both conflict with `3.`, which implicitly returns `None` when the second branch is done.

Since the first branch is empty aside from the `return`, both `1.` and `3.` can be collapsed to one path that *always*  returns a `Tree`.

```
def recursive_func(tree, n):
    if n > 0:
        permutations = get_permutations()
        for permutation in permutations:
            child_tree = recursive_func(Tree(permutation), n-1)
            tree.addChild(child_tree)
    return tree
```